# JS try won't catch a thrown error

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

Looking at the following code:

### HTML

```
<a href="#" id="href" onclick="onClick('it's', 'a', 'new', 'dawn')">foo</a>
```

### JS

```
function onClick() {

}

try {
  // Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list --> 
  // since the quotes don't match under the onclick='.. attribute
  href.onclick;
} catch (e) {
    // no propegation over here
}
```

I get the aformentioned exception inside the try statement, however, there's no passing into the catch statement.

It happens on both Chrome and FF and I've been wondering why.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wqob0x7d/1/

Comment: its a `SyntaxError` - you can't catch those because your code is bad.

Comment: Notice also, that the error to catch must be thrown from `try` block, obviously the inline code is not in that block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't catch syntax errors. They're not thrown at runtime — they are detected **before** the code is run. The parser can't tell what the code is supposed to mean because it doesn't conform to the syntax it expects, so it just throws up its little hands and produces that error.

That said, there *are* certain times when your code can be in control of errors thrown by the parser:

- when your code is using `eval()` or the Function constructor to turn strings into executable code. That implicitly involves the services of the parser, which will behave the same way with erroneous code.
- when using `JSON.parse()` to interpret a serialized object. That's a different parser, but you can catch its errors too.

Comment: Brilliant! there might be times when we'll be able to tackle it using ES6s Proxy feature, but for now, I've set myself with another solution specific to my problem. thank you!